# Problemas al instalar una aplicacion

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

estaba probando unas cosas en android studio y me doy cuenta de que no corre en android 5.0 ni 6.0, solo se ejecuta en 7.0.
Estoy usando compileSdkVersion 26, minSdkVersion 21 y targetSdkVersion 26 por lo que no debería tener ningún problema.
El error del logcat la verdad no lo entiendo. Cualquier ayuda sirve.

Gracias.

Este es el código:

```
public class Juego extends SurfaceView {

Personaje personaje;
Paint paint;
Bitmap imagen_personaje;

public Juego(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    paint = new Paint();
    imagen_personaje = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.personaje);
    personaje = new Personaje(this, imagen_personaje);
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), paint);

    personaje.onDraw(canvas);
    invalidate();
}
```

}

Personaje:

```
public class Personaje {

private Juego juego;
private Bitmap personaje;
Paint paint;

int x, y, inicio = 0, ancho, alto, currentFrame = 0,Horizontal = 1, Vertical = 8, frameLengthInMilliseconds = 150, cantFrames = 8;
long fps, timeThisFrame, lastFrameChangeTime = 0;



public Personaje(Juego juego, Bitmap personaje){

    this.juego = juego;
    this.personaje = personaje;
    this.ancho = personaje.getWidth() / Vertical;
    this.alto = personaje.getHeight() / Horizontal;

    paint = new Paint();
}

private void update() {

    long startFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (startFrame > lastFrameChangeTime + frameLengthInMilliseconds) {
        lastFrameChangeTime = startFrame;
        currentFrame++;
        if (currentFrame >= cantFrames) {

            currentFrame = 0;
        }
    }

    long startFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    timeThisFrame = System.currentTimeMillis() - startFrameTime;
    if (timeThisFrame >= 1) {
        fps = 1000 / timeThisFrame;
    }
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    update();

    int srcX = currentFrame * ancho;
    int srcY = alto * inicio;

    x = canvas.getWidth()/2;
    y = canvas.getHeight()/2;

    Rect src = new Rect(srcX, srcY, srcX + ancho, srcY + alto);
    Rect dst = new Rect(x, y, x + ancho, y + alto);

    canvas.drawBitmap(personaje, src, dst, null);
}
```

}

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.agusv.pruebaespacio3.MainActivity">

<com.example.agusv.pruebaespacio3.Juego
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
04-14 16:43:14.974 3752-3752/com.example.agusv.pruebaespacio3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.agusv.pruebaespacio3, PID: 3752
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.agusv.pruebaespacio3/com.example.agusv.pruebaespacio3.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.example.agusv.pruebaespacio3.Juego
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.example.agusv.pruebaespacio3.Juego
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                                at com.example.agusv.pruebaespacio3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.example.agusv.pruebaespacio3.Juego
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                at com.example.agusv.pruebaespacio3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                at com.example.agusv.pruebaespacio3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.example.agusv.pruebaespacio3.Personaje.<init>(Personaje.java:28)
                                                                                at com.example.agusv.pruebaespacio3.Juego.<init>(Juego.java:27)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                at com.example.agusv.pruebaespacio3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) que estas pasando a la clase `Personaje` esta referenciando a `null`. Por ende, al llamar los metodos de [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) con la referencia a `null` te causa:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference

El problema puede darse por 2 situaciones.

1. Estas tratando de obtener los recursos sin el contexto:

Haces:

```
imagen_personaje = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.personaje);
```

En vez de:

```
imagen_personaje = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.personaje);
```

2. Estas tratando de obtener un recurso `Drawable xml` y convertirlo a Bitmap, por lo que te devolvera `null`. Para este caso la solucion es la siguiente:

Para versiones `Android < API 22`

```
Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.personaje);
```

Otras alternativas: [Android getResources().getDrawable() deprecated API 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Una vez obtenido el Drawable, intenta convertirlo a Bitmap:

```
private Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Mis recomendaciones:

- Si vas a crear muchos objetos de tipo `Juego`, utiliza [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) para evitar el **OutOfMemory** y tener mejor performance al cargar las imagenes. Con esto ahorraras en crear el algoritmo para reciclar los `Bitmaps`.
- Valida siempre los posibles casos de `null` a menos que estes 100% seguro de que siempre tu valor estará referenciado de manera correcta.

Espero pueda ayudarte. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

¿es necesario que uses ConstraintLayoyut? Yo nunca lo uso porque me da problemas, porque se tiene que definir la característica de este layout que es que se expanda o contraiga. Yo en tu lugar usaría un RelativeLayout, solamente tienes que cambiar el XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.agusv.pruebaespacio3.MainActivity">

<com.example.agusv.pruebaespacio3.Juego
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Más no te sé decir, a mi el ConstraintLayout siempre me da problemas.

Un saludo, espero que te sirva

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta. Voy a probar cambiar el layout. A mi tampoco me gusta mucho el ConstraintLayoyut pero me lo crea por defecto cada vez que hago un nuevo proyecto

Comment: Ya, lo hace por defecto pero yo siempre lo cambio

Comment: No me funciono, gracias igual